# Python only returns JSON keys, but not values

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm working with a railroad API that returns JSON data about each train, such as the direction, speed, location, destination, etc.

I'm writing a simple function that will return only the trains that are going in the direction that I specify. I'm trying to do this in a for loop.

```
def getAllTrainsMatchingCriteria(line, direction):
     url = 'http://api.example.com/developer/api/v2/vehiclesbyroute?api_key=key&route='+line+'&format=json'
    try:
        response = (requests.get(url)).json()
    except:
        print('Unable to connect to API endpoint.')

    # Parse Data
    for trip in response['direction']:
        if trip['direction_name'] == direction:
            trains = []
            for train in trip['trip']:
                trains += train
            return trains
```

Here's an example of the data that I'm working with:

```
{
    "route_id": "Route",
    "route_name": "Route",
    "route_type": "2",
    "mode_name": "Commuter Rail",
    "direction": [
        {
        "direction_id": "0",
        "direction_name": "Outbound",
        "trip": [
            {
                "trip_id": "Train-800-Weekday",
                "trip_name": "8:00 Train from City",
                "trip_headsign": "Destination",
                "vehicle": {
                    "vehicle_id": "1701",
                     "vehicle_lat": "42.0341186523438",
                     "vehicle_lon": "-71.2189483642578",
                     "vehicle_bearing": "216",
                     "vehicle_speed": "0",
                     "vehicle_timestamp": "1510092937",
                     "vehicle_label": "1818"
                }
            },
            {
             "another example train"
            },
            {
             "another train, etc."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If I print train to the console within my for loop, I see all trains that match my criteria as I expected, and the data is structured properly.

If I print or return trains after my for loop, all I see is an array of keys, such as trip_id, trip_name, etc. No values or other data.

In this example, there is only one train that matches my criteria, but let's say there are 3. How can I return all three trains with all of the data intact?

Answer (score 0):

`return` exists the method at once, you should put it after the `for`-loop. Next, you expand the list `trains` with the dictionary `train`, meaning, appending all keys of `train` to the list:

```
def getAllTrainsMatchingCriteria(line, direction):
    url = 'http://api.example.com/developer/api/v2/vehiclesbyroute?api_key=key&route={}&format=json'.format(line)
    response = (requests.get(url)).json()

    # Parse Data
    trains = []
    for trip in response['direction']:
        if trip['direction_name'] == direction:
            trains.expand(trip['trip'])
    return trains
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so a few minutes after posting, I found another similar example where someone used .append() rather than += to add each item. Sure enough, that did the trick.

```
for trip in response['direction']:
    if trip['direction_name'] == direction:
        trains = []
        for train in trip['trip']:
            trains.append(train)
        return trains
```

I guess now I should figure out exactly why.